# Return specific fields from CMD

Tags: windows, command-line, zip, 7zip

I need to clean my output log with specific fields in command line.

Current code returns all fields, log information in a txt file.

`C:\Program Files\7-Zip>7z l "J:\FOLDER\FOLDER\*pattern*" > "C:\Users\me\Desktop\tst.txt"`

`Listing archive: PATH

Path = path_name

Type = zip

Physical Size = 0000011`

`Date   Size    Compressed  Name
----    -----   -------     -----

01.07.2019  0   111 file_name
01.07.2019  0   111 file_name`

I want my text output to return:

`Date       | Size | Compressed | Name
 01.07.2019  0      111          name`

Comment: `"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z" l "J:\FOLDER\FOLDER\*pattern*" | findstr /V /I "^$ ^7-zip ^Scanning ^Listing ^Path ^Type ^Physical ^Comment ^-- file,.*bytes files$ folders$ ^Archives ^Volumes ^Total"` or something alike?

Comment: @JosefZ - works perfectly! I tried to save it as output but no success while using `> "C:\Users\me\Desktop\tst.txt"` Still - goal achieved ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@JosefZ saved the day.

`"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z" l "J:\FOLDER\FOLDER\*pattern*" | findstr /V /I "^$ ^7-zip ^Scanning ^Listing ^Path ^Type ^Physical ^Comment ^-- file,.*bytes files$ folders$ ^Archives ^Volumes ^Total"`